# Uploaded images won't show admin: CMS/Pages

Tags: admin, image, cms, upload, tinymce

I'd like to know why the images I upload and integrate in pages show up in front office but not in the admin view.

Thanks for your help.

[What I get in the admin http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/280x200q90/902/GRtuS7.jpg](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/280x200q90/902/GRtuS7.jpg)

Comment: is it show in frontend?

Comment: Take a look @ http://www.websourceblog.com/2011/11/images-are-not-appearing-in-magento-cms-editor/

Comment: Can you post your CMS page code please

Comment: Yes @AmitBera, It actually shows in frontend.

Comment: @R.S : thanks for the link, but as long as my content appears on frontend, I think the problem is different.

Comment: @JasonTipton > The code looks like : <p style="text-align: center;"><img src="http://www.blabla.com/index.php/admin/cms_wysiwyg/directive/___directive/e3ttZWRpYSB1cmw9Ind5c2l[...]Bvd2VyLmpwZyJ9fQ,,/key/805d285[...]81def9eea3f9/" alt="bla bla bla" />

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are creating the links by hand.  Try using the built in Insert Image tool instead.  Using your example image paths would change from:

```
<img src="blabla.com/index.php/admin/cms_wysiwyg/directive/___directive/image.png" alt="bla bla bla" />
```

to:

```
<img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/image.png"}}" alt="bla bla bla" />
```

*note: I modified your example to include closing double quotes on the image source, removed the semicolon, and added an image name.  Also, I did not include your folder structure of 'admin/cms_wysiwyg/directive/___directive' but you could create those folders if they do not exist yet or click through them in the Insert Image tool if they do already exist.

Comment: Well, here is the point : I already use the built in insert image tool which, as soon as I clicked insert : [image](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/150x100q90/538/5Honr4.jpg). On frontend howerver, the image is properly linked : bla.com/media/wysiwig/folder/imagename.jpg